# how can i make wordpress display posts from the second top 10 posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

i am using this code to display in my main page the posts by number of views

```
        function wh_post_display_order_view($query) {
    if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $query->set('meta_key', 'whpp_track_post_views');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        $query->set('order', 'DESC');   

    }
}        add_action('pre_get_posts','wh_post_display_order_view');
```

how can i make it display posts from the second top 10 posts?
ex : i want the 1st post appears to be number 11 in the most viewed posts

Comment: You are looking for the `offset` property - `$query->set('offset', 10)`.  Review [WP_Query documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for all of the possible arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `offset` parameter like so:

```
$query->set('offset', 10);
```

More about pagination and WP Query class [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters)